# Are there two separate Mewtwos?

Tags: pokemon

In the first movie and the anime series, Mewtwo's voice clearly indicates that Mewtwo is male. In the 16th movie, Mewtwo appears to be  female. It was then shown that that Mewtwo can mega evolve into Mewtwo Y. From this, is it possible that there are two Mewtwos, where the male is Mewtwo X and the female is Mewtwo Y? I know that in the game, Mewtwo does not have a gender, but this is from the anime's perspective.

Comment: I've noticed that all of your posts have significant grammatical errors. You can check your grammar [at this site](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck#.V8PXbE0rKUk) if English is not your first language or you are unsure of your writing.

Comment: VA gender != gender of character. Ash's Pikachu is male but is voiced by a female. On a less-anime example, all characters of south park are voiced by 2 people, both male.

Comment: @ThePickleTickler sorry, baout that, i'll make sure i use caps from now on

Comment: @ardaozkal i have fixed my question

Comment: In Italy Goku (from Dragon Ball) was voiced by a female for quite some series... Does this mean that he is a transgender lesbian female?

Comment: Bart Simpson is voiced by a woman, yet in the Simpsons Movie, we can clearly see he's male (or at least has male genitals). Judging the gender of someone by their voice is not accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The evidence overwhelmingly indicates that there are two Mewtwos. Firstly, in 
[*Genesect and the Legend Awakened*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M16), Mewtwo didn't give any indication of recognizing Ash, even though it should have known him from the movie *Mewtwo Strikes Back*. This indicates it was a different Mewtwo. Secondly, it has its own backstory in the special episode [*Mewtwo: Prologue to Awakening*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SS026). I haven't seen the special, so I couldn't say for certain whether the events therein completely contradict the idea of there being only one Mewtwo, but what I've read indicates that the second Mewtwo's creators survived, which contradicts the fact that the first Mewtwo killed its creators.

The evidence for either Mewtwo having a gender, however, is nearly nonexistent. You submit the voice actor/actress for each Mewtwo as evidence of its gender, but I would contend that this is very insignificant. Especially for animals (or Pokémon), an actress can play the role of a male character and an actor can play a female character. Shaymin from [*Giratina and the Sky Warrior*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shaymin_(M11)) is an example to consider. In the English dub of the movie, Shaymin's voice actress used a more masculine voice for when Shaymin turned into its Sky Forme, but used a feminine voice for Shaymin's Land Forme. This demonstrates that the voice acting isn't a good indicator of a Pokémon's gender.

Furthermore, the anime rarely reveals the gender of any Pokémon. For example, just look how few of [Ash's Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash_Ketchum#Pok.C3.A9mon.) have confirmed genders. Of his Pokémon from Kanto and Johto, only the genders of Pikachu (male), Bayleef (female), and Butterfree (male) have been confirmed. Notably, his Pokémon from Unova have the highest percentage of confirmed genders. This is because his Snivy knew the move attract, the effectiveness of which depends on the Pokémon being of the opposite gender.

And there you get to my point: The gender of a Pokémon is only revealed in the anime when there is reason to. The gender of Mewtwo really doesn't matter, and there is no reliable information from the anime as a result. If we're just going by the anime, we don't know the gender of either Mewtwo.

**Edit**: In the *Black and White: Adventures in Unova and Beyond* episode [*To Catch a Rotom!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/BW128), Professor Oak confirms that Rotom is genderless after an attract move by Iris's Emolga fails. The existence of genderless Pokémon in the anime is likely an indicator that the anime follows the games in this matter, and that Mewtwo is also genderless.

Answer (score 10):

I did some research and it appears that there are actually two different Mewtwos, as you suggest. I know this sounds a bit outlandish at first, but it is mentioned and supported in numerous different sources.

From [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/66716994):

> In game: genderless
>   Real mewtwo from the first movie: male
>   New mewtwo from genesect movie: female, apparently

From [Pokemon Database](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/242280/what-gender-is-mewtwo):

> The original Mewtwo, created by team rocket (First Movie & Mewtwo Returns), was a male.
>   This is the moody Mewtwo you know best.
>
> The second Mewtwo appears in Genesect and the Legend Awakened and is female.
>
> There is no real evidence for exactly who created this Mewtwo, but it may have been another team following Giovanni's original plans. It could also have to do with the "multiple parallel universes" mentioned to exist in ORAS.
>
> If this were to be the case, this Mewtwo would have been created at abut the same time in about the same circumstances, but was born a female and may have never met Ash.

In general, it appears that the movies can sometimes operate within different timelines of the regular anime, so these *multiple parallel universe* theories can exist separately.

From the [Bulbapedia entry for Mewtwo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), it states that Mewtwo is genderless, but Bulbapedia refers to the games and not the anime/movies.

You can also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIHEXPEdJI8), where a semi-popular YouTuber discusses the gender of Mewtwo (and reaches the same conclusion that there are two Mewtwos).

Comment: The movies don't confirm the gender of the mewtwo's we see though. Do they? So they could still be gender less. I would not trust the word of fans that say one is male and the other is female just because once has a male voice and one has a female voice. Especially considering that it's officially stated to be gender less. Fair enough if in the story they specifically state their gender. But that hasn't happened as far as I'm aware. Furthermore there are plenty examples of males sounding feminine and females sounding masculine.

Comment: Those sources you're using are mostly comments by fans and therefore not authoritative.

Comment: doesn't bulbapedia do info on the anime episodes/movies and the anime characters?

Comment: @Dragon Yes, it does: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo_(Best_Wishes_series)

Answer (score 1):

The Mewtwo in the first movie and in Mewtwo Returns is confirmed male - from Giovanni saying "Good Boy" when Mewtwo willingly goes into the trap made by Giovanni. And the more masculine voice just helps validate this, but the fact that Giovanni stated him as a "boy" for me validates he is a male.

As for Mewtwo in the Pokémon the Movie: Genesect and the Legend Awakened - it is a different Mewtwo. It is voiced by a woman in both Japanese and English dubs, but there is no actual confirmation of its gender by pronouns or etc. We "assume" it is a female but there is no real indication of its gender as there was with the first Mewtwo. Also, this Mewtwo is clearly a different Mewtwo by the choices of voice actors, and also the fact that Ash recognized it as Mewtwo, but the Mewtwo from the Genesect movie didn't recognize Ash. Ash also 'acknowledged' it was a different Mewtwo in the Mewtwo x Genesect Movie. This Mewtwo can also mega evolve to Mega Mewtwo Y at will, which the original Mewtwo from the first movies never could.

Comment: This makes the most sense out of all of the answers, IMO. +1 for being clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are two mewtwos, this was stated by Director Kunihiko Yuyama: "When you think about the Mewtwo from the first movie, Mewtwo Strikes Back, you think about lines like "Who am I?" and how there was this running theme of Mewtwo wondering about itself and how it relates to the world around it."

"The Mewtwo in this film has actually gone out into the world and has expanded its worldview.  And it's started to be concerned about this world and those in it, and when you compare it to the previous Mewtwo, you'll definitely feel like it's gotten past one of its limitations."

"This Mewtwo is not the same Mewtwo from the first movie.  What part will this Mewtwo, who's actually gone out into the world, play in this movie?"
 As you can clearly read it is a separate individual and not the mewtwo we saw first. Here is my source: http://dogasu.bulbagarden.net/movies/bw_genosect_mewtwo/extreme_speed_genosect_awakening_mewtwo_director_yuyama_comment.html