# Is the Mewtwo in Detective Pikachu a Mewtwo we know?

Tags: pokemon, detective-pikachu

In the first Pokemon Movie we see that Mewtwo is actually artificially created by Team Rocket and not a naturally occurring Pokemon.

According to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/36079/1587) there are 2 Mewtwo's and the second female one is still possibly artificially created.

In the trailers for *Detective Pikachu* (I have not seen the movie yet) we see Mewtwo appear in it. I am wondering if this Mewtwo is one we already know from the anime movies? Or are there now possibly 3 Mewtwo's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoilers ahead.

Haven't watched the movies or anime, but I play the games, and according to [this article](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/detective-pikachu-has-deep-ties-to-the-first-pokem/1100-6466825/), this Mewtwo

> *is the same Mewtwo that appeared in the original Pokemon anime and movie two decades ago.* The movie referred to here is *Pokémon: The First Movie*. This was the Mewtwo from the Kanto region which escaped Team Rocket.

Comment: I saw the movie, so I can confirm this is correct